# How to activate the FileSystemObject in Visual Basic Express 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I do have a "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference and added the "Scrrun.dll" file in Projects > References.
But the code below triggers an error.

> Error 1   Type 'FileSystemObject' is not defined. C:\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb  6   24  WindowsApplication1
>   Error 2   Type 'Folder' is not defined.   C:\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb          7   20  WindowsApplication1

```
   Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
   Dim fld As Folder
```

Comment: `FileSystemObject` isn't in .Net, isn't it VB6?  What is it you're trying to do?  There's likely a .Net way to do it...

Comment: I'm trying to use the Filesystem to search for all folders and files with a specific name.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use VB.NET, I suggest that you do it "the .NET way" instead of relying on old COM libraries: Have a look at the [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx).

That being said, let me answer your question: The objects you seek are in the `Scripting` namespace, so the following should fix your issue:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject()
Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
```

Alternatively, you can just *import* the namespace:

```
Imports Scripting

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim fso As New FileSystemObject()
        Dim fld As Folder
        ...
    End Sub
End Module
```